# Add days to datetime

Tags: stata

I would like to add 24 hours or 1 day to my timedate variable in Stata.

```
read_date               Desired_date
2009-01-01 14:00:00     2009-01-02 14:00:00
```

I formatted my read_date with `format read_date %tcCCYY-NN-DD_HH:MM:SS` which worked without errors.

I have been trying to add days by adding 86400 seconds as: `replace Desired_date = Desired_date+86400` It executes without errors but only time portion increases by an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units of date-times in Stata are **milliseconds** as documented in `help datetime`. 86400 milliseconds is 86.4 seconds, not 1 hour.

You need to add the number of milliseconds in 1 day which is 24 * 60 * 60000, although it is neither necessary nor advisable to type that expression or its result. Adding `cofd(1)` adds the number of milliseconds in one day.

```
. di %tc  clock("4 May 2022 19:00:00", "DMY hms")
04may2022 19:00:00

. di %tc  clock("4 May 2022 19:00:00", "DMY hms") + cofd(1)
05may2022 19:00:00
```

I used `display` (`di`) for convenience with scalar constants. All you need to do is add `cofd(1)` in your `replace` statement.

.

Comment: Thanks, I used it as replace Desired_date = Desired_date+cofd(1) and it worked! Can you please suggest how to subtract these datetimes to get number of days?(for different set of datetime variables)

Comment: That is a new question or questions.  If you want to calculate in terms of days you could map to daily dates using `dofc()` or divide differences in date-times by the same magic constant `cofd(1)`.